# Java determine the type of class for a list in generic class

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class

I'm new to Java generics and I'm currently stuck with determining the type of Pair object (apache's) in a list.

I have two classes A and B and both have a method that's doing the exact same operation (code duplication).

The method is something like this:

```
private List<Pair<String, A>> deduplicateItems(List<Pair<String, A>> list) {
   
   List<Pair<String, A>> deduplicatedItems = new ArrayList<>();
   list.forEach(item-> {
     //do something
     deduplicatedItems.add(item);
   });

}
```

The same exact method is in class B (the type of Value in Pair is B).

I would like to create a generic abstract class that can handle this operation.

I have so far:

```
public abstract class AbstractHelper<V> {
     
      private List<Pair<String, V>> deduplicateItems(List<Pair<String, V>> list) {
      
      List<Pair<String, V>> deduplicatedItems = new ArrayList<>();
    
      //problem here determining the type of class for this generic
   });

      }
}
```

I would like to determine the type of V and cast that to be able to access the get() methods.

Is using `list.get(0) instanceof A` the right way to do? I feel like that maybe too naive but I could be wrong here.

Comment: You can't, but you shouldn't need to.

Answer (score 0):

Make the method generic:

```
private <T> List<Pair<String, T>> deduplicateItems(List<Pair<String, T>> list) {
   List<Pair<String, T>> deduplicatedItems = new ArrayList<>();
   list.forEach(item-> {
     //do something
     deduplicatedItems.add(item);
   });
   return deduplicatedItems;
}
```

If A and B both implement the same interface or extend a common parent class, and you want "do something" to interact with the elements in that way, put a bound on T:

```
private <T extends MyCommonType> List<Pair<String, T>> deduplicateItems(List<Pair<String, T>> list) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be checking the type.  You definitely should not write something like `if (element instanceof A) { } else if (element instanceof B) { } else if` etc.

The problem is that your method doesn’t know how to check two instances of type V for equality.  Since your method doesn’t have that information, you should force callers to provide that information:

```
private List<Pair<String, V>> deduplicateItems(
                    List<Pair<String, V>> list,
                    BiPredicate<? super V, ? super V> equalityChecker) {

    List<Pair<String, V>> deduplicatedItems = new ArrayList<>();
    List<V> existingValues = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Pair<String, V>> pair : list) {
        V value = pair.getValue();
        if (existingValues.stream().noneMatch(
            v -> equalityChecker.test(v, value)) {

            existingValues.add(value);
            deduplicatedItems.add(pair);
        }
    }

    return deduplicatedItems;
}
```

[BiPredicate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html) is an interface that tests two values and returns a boolean based on them.  An example usage might be:

```
List<Pair<String, String>> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
numbers.add(Pair.of("1", "ONE"));
numbers.add(Pair.of("1", "one"));
numbers.add(Pair.of("2", "TWO"));
numbers.add(Pair.of("2", "two"));
numbers.add(Pair.of("3", "THREE"));
numbers.add(Pair.of("3", "three"));

List<Pair<String, String>> uniqueNumbers =
    deduplicateItems(numbers, String::equalsIgnoreCase);
```

If every class that V will ever represent has a reliable [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method defined, you don’t need the second argument, and you can use a Set to make checking for duplicate values more efficient:

```
private List<Pair<String, V>> deduplicateItems(List<Pair<String, V>> list) {

    List<Pair<String, V>> deduplicatedItems = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<V> existingValues = new HashSet<>();

    for (Pair<String, V>> pair : list) {
        if (existingValues.add(pair.getValue())) {
            deduplicatedItems.add(pair);
        }
    }

    return deduplicatedItems;
}
```

The above works because the [Set.add method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#add(E)) makes this guarantee:

> **Returns:**
>
> `true` if this set did not already contain the specified element

Of course, you can also define both of the above deduplicateItems methods, and let calling code decide which is appropriate in a given situation.